# Subprocess Popen fails to execute if python exits straight after

Tags: subprocess, python-3.7

The following code fails to launch my application on Python 3.7 on Mac 10.15.3.

```py
import subprocess

cmdLine = "/Applications/RV.app/Contents/MacOS/RV"

subprocess.Popen(cmdLine, shell=True)
```

It doesn't throw an error, it just doesn't do anything.
If I run the same code in Python 2.7 it works correctly and launches the application, without waiting for it.

I discovered by debugging and walking through the subprocess code that it actually launched when I did that. Which lead me to try:

```py
import subprocess
import time

cmdLine = "/Applications/RV.app/Contents/MacOS/RV"

subprocess.Popen(cmdLine, shell=True)
time.sleep(1)
```

Which then worked. It seems that the `Popen` command is not managing to spawn the separate process before python exits. Am I doing something wrong here?

**Edit:**

It appears like it also has something to do with the actual application I'm trying to launch. Launching the Calculator app or Firefox, for example, does work without the added sleep.

Comment: try with ```subprocess.Popen(cmdLine, shell=True).check_output()```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately, that doesn't seem to consistently work.
It seems to work some of the time, which I guess we could put down to it causing the python process to sometimes live just long enough to allow it to launch.